# Wordpress Admin-Like Menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, wordpress, menu

Can anyone provide me with a link to a tutorial or plugin, preferably in jQuery that will allow me to create a menu that not only collapses vertically (jQueryUI's Accordian), but also collapses horizontally? No matter what I google, all I can find are the vertical ones, and the Wordpress one is super-integrated to its core, as far as I can tell.

EDIT: Here are some screenshots. The first is normal, the second is expanded / collapsed vertically, the third is collapsed horizontally.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Sorry, what is it you are asking? You want a menu that collapses vertically and horizontally??? So confused, is there an example?

Comment: I think he means. the menu links to collapse vertically, and the whole menu itself slideLeft? but this could be anyones guess lol :)

Comment: @Neurofluxation: Added screenshots for clarity :)

Comment: @Val: Added screenshots for clarity :)

Comment: @josh there are a number of ways u can do this

Comment: @Val: I'm aware there are some ways that I can do it, but I would rather just drop in an existing solution. It is for my company's administration menu, which is an abomination, and my boss has given me ~.5 hour to find a new one, and install it, if I want, so I don't really have time to write one from scratch.

Comment: its dead simple u can do it in 20 minutes :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try jQuery UI i think thats what WP uses
http://jqueryui.com/

Answer (score 2):

You can use a plugin like Accordion or [Collapsible Menu](http://www.mathachew.com/sandbox/collapsible-menu/) (a bit more wordpress like) for the vertical collapse, and then put that menu in a div that can collapse horizontally with a plugin like [TabSlideOut](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/tab-slide-out). Or just change the width of the menu DIV with .animate().

Also notice how the wordpress removes the text from the menus but leaves the icons.

Answer (score 1):

html

```
<div class="hide-menu">Hide Menu</div>
<ul id="menu">
    <li><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Link 2</a></li>
    <li>
         <ul class="subs"><li><a href="">Subs</a></li></ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

jQuery

```
$('.hide-menu').bind('click',function (){
    $('#menu').animate({width:30});//can always extend this.
    //u can use the if statement or toggle if u need toggling feature
});
$('#menu').children('li').bind('click',function (){
     //here u can hide the subs
})
```

now ofcourse the above is not going to work exactly like wordpress or may not work at all but you get the idea :) I hope

Comment: btw u can make sure that when `#menu` is small u need `overflow:hidden;` and then `overflow:visible` when maximised :) (in css that is)

Answer (score 1):

I will toggle a class, as you can see there is an arrow that toggles horizontaly. So, just add or remove class and with CSS make the effect done, like this:

```
$(mi-button).click(function(e){
     $(mi-menu-selector).toggleClass(your-class);
     e.preventDefault;

});
```

with Css show or hide the text of each li of your menu.

```
.hide-horizontal{
text-indent:-999em;
}
```

Comment: You will maintain the Icons and the CSS properties. As in Wordpress Admin Menu.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use responsive design to achieve this.

You can use CSS media queries:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Responsive_Web_Design

http://mediaqueri.es/